# Back button from xib to storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Currently I develop with a StoryBoard for the iPad. Additionally I add a ViewController.xib file with a view. Now I want to back button from xib to storyboard. My code is below but this is not working.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:initViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How do you present this view controller? From a storyboard scene?

Comment: storyboard to xib I am using below code. 
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.detailTextLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"item title: %@", cellText);
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    vc.strFullName = cellText;
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];

Comment: I hope my answer can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can present the View Controller from a storyboard scene, using 
`- presentViewController:animated:completion:` (e.g. for a modally scenario)

```
ViewController *vc= [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

then, you can add a custom back button

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", @"Back from ViewController.XIB") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

and dismiss it:

```
- (void)backAction:(id)sender{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: @Saravanan, you're welcome! By the way, you can accept this answer if you find it helpful for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the `navigationController`.

In your active view controller init the new view controller like this.

```
UIViewController *initViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"YourNibFile" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController:initViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And to dismiss.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:self completion:nil];
```